# Convert many images to one PDF on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, pdf, images, png

How can I convert about 100 PNGs to one PDF on a Mac? I'm open to using the command line if it helps.

I have tried using iPhoto, but it quits, not sure why. Saving from Preview doesn't quite do what I want. Thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate question on AskDifferent: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11163/how-do-i-combine-two-or-more-images-to-get-a-single-pdf-file

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you have Leopard (10.5 or later) or Lion the easiest way is to use [Preview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(software)). Just do the following:

1. Open the first image in Preview
2. Show the the sidebar (Shift-Command-D)
3. Drag any additional images to the sidebar
4. Go to File > Print (Command P)
5. In the PDF dropdown list select Save as PDF

That's it! You should now have a PDF containing all your images.

If that doesn't work for you, you should look at any third-party solutions such as [Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html) which has a combine feature or [PDFLab](http://www.iconus.ch/fabien/products/pleng/pleng.html).

Comment: +1 - My suggested solution as well.  I've used this method to combine several PDFs by printing, then choosing "Save as PDF" from the print panel.

Comment: For me in Snow Leopard, File > Print only printed the first image. I had to select File > Print Selected Images in order to print all of them.

Comment: Shift-Cmd-D didn't open sidebar for me, I had to explicitly use View -> Thumbnails  (option - Cmd - 2) - on mac os x el capitan v10.11.3 - otherwise the instructions worked a charm.

Comment: It's 2018 and this method still works like charm. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: unfortunatelly this method will not save rotation if it different across images

Comment: not having a printer does not allow me to hit print and save the pdf

Comment: OP stated: to be open to use command line if it helps, has 100 files, saving from Preview doesn't quite do what I want. It makes no sense that this is the accepted answer. The answer that `kqw` presents ticks all boxes.

Comment: doesnt seem to work anymore

Answer (score 81):

I prefer using command line tools such as ImageMagick for this type of work. You can install IM with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Afterwards you can do

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

and if the resulting PDF is a bit too big you can try:

```
convert -quality 60 *.jpg output.pdf
```

Of course ImageMagick also works on other Unix systems, and even on cygwin.

(If you want a specific order you can also write out the `.jpg` filenames one by one. Or use `*` and rename the `.jpg`s in alphabetical order.)

Comment: after running this command, every image that *.jpg expanded to was overwritten with the first image, and only the final one was saved to PDF

Comment: @user5359531 Strange. For me this has worked perfectly many times before and to double check I just tried it again. No problem. What was the exact command you ran? And which version? `convert --version|head -1` gives me `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.5-2 Q16 x86_64 2016-07-13 http://www.imagemagick.org`

Comment: how do you order the pages?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Name the image files in the order that you want the pages to appear in the PDF.

Comment: This. It works beautifully, for any aspect ratio - the Print answer above is more of a hack than anything else.

Comment: this is the best answer for me

Comment: Works beautifully for the use case I just ran employing `ImageMagick 7.1.0-17` on `macOS 10.14.6 buildversion 18G9323`.

Answer (score 11):

My method is similar to Marcus's, but works a little better for me when the images are all different sizes and you don't want the PDF to just be all 8.5x11 but to keep each page the size of the original image.

1. Open the first image in Preview
2. Show thumbnails (Command-option-2)
3. Drag any additional images to the sidebar

After this we diverge:

1. Select all image thumbnails in the sidebar (select one by clicking, then Command-A)
2. File > Export Selected Images...
3. Select or create a folder to hold your temporary images, set Format to PDF, and click Choose
4. Close all original images
5. Open the LAST exported PDF in Preview (this will become the last page)
6. Drag all the other exported PDFs to the sidebar and drop ON TOP of the thumbnail for the exported PDF you just opened
7. This should create a multipage PDF with the images in the same order they were in the Finder. Rename it so you can find it easily, save and you're done.

Comment: This method worked very well for me. The Accepted Answer is very convenient, but as @Dave mentioned, doesn't work so well if your images are different sizes. The Accepted Answer's method also results in a margin around the edge of the PDF, presumably because the print dialog automatically adds a bleed edge. Also, Preview allows you to drag and drop _all_ the other PDFs and add them to the first (or last) PDF in one fell swoop. You can also reorder the pages in the resulting PDF by dragging and dropping.

Comment: Doesn't work on Yosemite. Step 2 shows a warning alert and exits the process.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend the Python CLI program `img2pdf` for lossless conversion:

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

Example usage:

```
img2pdf img1.png img2.jpg -o out.pdf
```

Comment: to install on macos use: pip3 install img2pdf

Comment: I use it like this: img2pdf * -o out.pdf

Comment: It is 2023, and this tool has worked perfectly for me on macOS 12.6, and it is exceptionally fast (120 iPhone photos in less than a second).

Answer (score 2):

On more current versions of OSX, you may be better off using the native command line tool `sips` - see [the answered Stack Overflow question 6349984](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349984/shell-script-to-change-pdf-files-to-png-mac-os-10-3), which converts from pdf to png. It should be far easier to script `sips` (which has been available since ~2009) than click multiple times within Preview.

Essentially,

```
sips -s format pdf input-png-file-path --out output-pdf-file-path
```

Answer (score 2):

## MacOS 12.6

Allows you to do this in 3 seconds:

1. In *Finder* Mark all PNGs you want to convert
2. Right click
3. Select *Quick Actions*
4. Select *Create PDF*

Bonus this **also works** with if you have **mixed file types**: E.g. If you want to convert JPEGs and PNGs and PDFs into one single PDF!

[image]

Comment: It works. However you should check for resulting image quality because this operation does image compression silently. The drop in quality could be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way is to use the rather overlooked app Automator, that you find in the Applications folder.

This link shows exactly how: [Use Automator to combine your research photos into one PDF](http://miriamposner.com/blog/use-automator-to-combine-your-research-photos-into-one-pdf/)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.